# Periodic polarizable QM/MM embedding

Tags: molecular-dynamics, software-recommendations, one-topic-per-answer, cp2k, qmmm

Are there any standalone open source software codes available for periodic polarizable QM/MM embedding MD simulations? In my knowledge, CP2K only has the option for electrostatic embedding and other software such as GROMACS or CHARMM require coupling with Gaussian or ORCA electronic structure codes. Non-periodic implementations are also welcome but I am looking for periodic implementations.

Comment: My +1 brought you to 1000+ points :) Based on reading the question it looked like there was a slight difference between the question's body and the title. Is the question specifically for "periodic" polarizable QM/MM embedding? I changed the title to reflect that, since it looked to be the case based on the body of the question.

Comment: @NikeDattani Thanks :). Yes, my priority is for periodic implementations, but non periodic implementations are also welcome.

Comment: the polarizable part is  tricky. Maybe your best bet is to look at QM/QM' (quantum mechanics,quantum mechanics) methods with point charge embedding. These have infinite long range electrostatic interactions thanks to Ewald summation and also are polarizable thanks to the QM'

Comment: I have heard that NWChem can do QM/MM and also periodic boundary conditions. However, I don't know if NWChem can use polarizable forcefields. If you really need that then you can probably use QM/semi-empirical via the ONIOM module.

Comment: @ShoubhikRMaiti The Gaussian idea is feasible. But do you know, if it is possible, to run MD with ONIOM in Gaussian?

Comment: @mykd As far as I know, MD runs only need methods that have analytic gradients. So, ONIOM should run MD, as long as both methods have analytic gradients available i.e. HF, DFT, etc. Also Gaussian is not open source btw.

Comment: @mykd Does it have to be open-source (e.g. because you need to see the source code), or is it enough for it to just be free of license fees?

Comment: @NikeDattani I guess "free of license fees" would work as well...

Comment: Hi @mykd it's been a while (over 1 year since this question was asked and about 6 months since my last edit!), have you made any progress on finding an answer to this?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if the OP addresses questions/suggestions in the comments or anyone else wants to give an answer.